# Why does this not create a table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

The code connects perfectly but it doesn't create a table why is this?

```
<?php

include "connect.php";

$table = "TestTable";
mysql_query ("ALTER TABLE '$table' ADD 'TITLE' TEXT NOT NULL");


?>
```

connect.php:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", test, password);
mysql_select_db($db, $con);
?>
```

Comment: Try CREATE instead of ALTER http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: Do you want to create a table or modify it? 'Alter' is used to Modify an existing table...

Comment: Remove the quotes around `'$table'` or replace with backticks; and possibly the same for `ADD 'TITLE'`

Comment: Doesnt work either :/

Comment: As stated, use `CREATE` (*if you wish to create*), and then use what I also said in my comment above in regards to the quotes.

Comment: I've used create and i removed the quotes around it, it still doesn't work. The line looks like this `mysql_query ("CREATE TABLE $table ADD TITLE TEXT NOT NULL");`

Comment: [`Consult my answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22484633/) @user3364498 tested and working using the `mysqli_*` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing is to use CREATE. This code should do the trick:

```
<?php

include "connect.php";

$table = "TestTable";
mysql_query ("CREATE TABLE '$table' ('TITLE' TEXT NOT NULL"));

)

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to CREATE a table, then both the `ALTER` and the `ADD` command are nonsense, try

```
CREATE TABLE $table (TITLE TEXT NOT NULL);
```

Comment: This helped me, thanks!
I want it to alter the table but create it if it doesnt exist

Comment: This feature does not seems currently implemented in MySQL (at least 5.2): http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3706 . You should go trough the hard way of reading the columns from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. see here: http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/mysql/howto_add_column_unless_exists.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use the following if you wish to "create" a table if it does not exist, and alter it if it does exist.

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

$table = "TestTable";
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$table` (`TITLE` TEXT NOT NULL)");
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `$table` ADD `TITLE` TEXT NOT NULL");

?>
```

---

### Edit

The following has been tested and working on my server (*using the `mysqli_*` function*):

```
<?php
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');  
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'xxx');

$mysqli = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)  
OR die("could not connect");

$table = "TestTable";
mysqli_query($mysqli,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$table` (`TITLE` TEXT NOT NULL)");
mysqli_query($mysqli,"ALTER TABLE `$table` ADD `TITLE` TEXT NOT NULL");

?>
```